# link to a section on the page with WP menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I don't know much php but I have a parallax template and different sections which are technically pages created in wp-admin. So for example page 2 is:

```
    <!-- Section #2 -->
<section id="middle" data-speed="4" data-type="background">
        <div class="container">
            <?php query_posts('page_id=' . of_get_option('home_page_2', 'no entry' )); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php global $more;   
                $more = 0;
                the_content(""); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </section></a>
```

Now I want to modify the main wp menu at the top to link to this section. I have tried doing it with html so I wrapepd that whole section around an `<a id="2">` tag and recalling it in the menu with website.com/#2 and this works partially BUT it now sees that whole section as a hyperlink thus messing up its formatting. Is there another way of doing this with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you need correctly, but in order to link to an element on the page, you could do the following:

- **Option 1:** Set an `id` attribute to the element:

```html
<section id="mysection">...</section>
```

- **Option 2:** create an empty anchor tag with an `id` attribute at the top of the *section* element:

```html
<a id="mysection"></a>
<section>
    <h2>My Section</h2>
    <!-- ... -->
</section>
```

Then target the section's id with your anchor tag:

```html
<a href="#mysection">Go to My Section</a>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/hgr3P/)**.

Comment: Excellent thanks a lot! I didn't know option 1 was a possibility but that worked since I already had the section id in place.